# Unfocus EditText when keyboard is dismissed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I want to achieve a simple task of *unfocusing* `EditText` (not hide cursor) when keyboard is dismissed, either by hitting the done or the return button. All I can find so far is

`window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN)`

But it is only good when the activity is first opened up. After keyboard is dismissed, text field is left in an awkward focused state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could listen for an event when keyboard is dismissed and then use `editText.clearFocus();` when that event happens.

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android) for listening to keyboard dismiss events

Comment: what if I have three edit texts and want to clear focus

Comment: then call `clearFocus();` function on all of them when keyboard is dismissed. Simple.

Comment: Worked, can't believe this is how Android still works in 2018

Comment: It does actually have these kind of quirks, but we have to deal with it at the moment. Future is bright i think :)

Comment: If your are adding dynamic component you can get the child components from the parent and loop each element and you can clear the focus

Comment: For checking for keyboard dismissal, this answer was simple, didn't feel like a hack, and worked beautifully for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/53013309/3718756

Answer (score 3):

I can't believe this is the easiest solution I could find to this problem (really, Android?):

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText {

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENDCALL) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(CustomEditText.this.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    CustomEditText.this.clearFocus();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            this.clearFocus();
        }
        return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the focus from edit text and also manage the enable/disable edit text.

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin** version:

```
class CustomEditText: AppCompatEditText {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle)

    override fun onKeyPreIme(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            clearFocus()
        }
        return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<com.youappdomain.view.CustomEditText
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```