# How can I check if enter on my keyboard is clicked?

Tags: android, onclick, key, onclicklistener, enter

This Question is no duplicate.

I want to check if *enter* on my keyboard is clicked.

This code is the most helpful for me:

```
 edittext.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "it works", Toast
                    .LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But it only works with the keyboard of my pc and not on my phone.
I don't know weather it's important, but I am using a Fragment.

Here is my XML:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:padding="10dp"/>
```

I looked at **ALL** [These acticles](https://www.google.com/search?q=android%20check%20wather%20enter%20is%20clicked%20site:stackoverflow.com&client=firefox-b-ab&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjzvLy6xaTeAhXO_KQKHeHwAEoQrQIoBDAAegQICRAO&biw=1280&bih=888) and I tried every code, but nothing worked.

**EDIT**

I read a comment and so I want to add:

I am talking About Software Keyboard.

Comment: are you talking about Software Keyboard or Hardware Keyboard?

Comment: @JoaquinAlvarez About Software Keyboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is dependence on `android:imeOptions=""` of your EditText.
Example, `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {        
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
            //do something
        }
    return false;
    }
});
```

UPD:
Add `android:inputType="text"` to your EditText in xml file

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:padding="10dp"/>
```

Comment: It changes nothing :(

Comment: What is your 'android:imeOptions'?

Comment: Not working too :( Does it work for you? Maybe it's the fault of my Device or Emulator.

Comment: @Bäumesindgrün give me a 5 minutes

Comment: Thank you very much :) It works, you are really a livesaver!